# Flutter Web Dio XMLHttpRequest error uploading large files

Tags: flutter, dio

In a Flutter app I'm trying to upload large audio files to a go server and save them to Wasabi s3.

I can see my server log returning a status code 200 for the OPTIONS request but no post request and no errors. In my go server I am using the chi router and have added handler header to allow CORS from anywhere. My app is large and everything else works fine. The authorization bearer token is also being passed in the request.

I have already made the changes to disable web security and also tested the upload page on my production flutter server where it also fails.

Api log for the options request

```
"OPTIONS http://api.mydomain.com/transcript/upload/audio/file/2 HTTP/1.1" from 123.12.0.1:48558 - 200 0B in 39.061µs
```

Here are the errors I can glean from Flutter

```
DioExceptionType.connectionError
https://api.mydomain.com/transcript/upload/audio/file/2
https://api.mydomain.com/transcript/upload/audio/file/2
{Content-Type: application/octet-stream, Authorization: Bearer my-token, Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *}
```

Relevant api code

```
r := chi.NewRouter()

r.Use(middleware.RequestID)
r.Use(middleware.Logger)
r.Use(middleware.Recoverer)
r.Use(middleware.URLFormat)
r.Use(render.SetContentType(render.ContentTypeJSON))
r.Use(cors.Handler(cors.Options{
    AllowedOrigins:   []string{"*"},
    AllowedMethods:   []string{"GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"},
    AllowedHeaders:   []string{"Accept", "Authorization", "Content-Type", "X-CSRF-Token"},
    ExposedHeaders:   []string{"Link"},
    AllowCredentials: false,
    MaxAge:           300, // Maximum value not ignored by any of major browsers
}))
```

---

```
const maxUploadSize = 500 * 1024 * 1024 // 500 MB

id := chi.URLParam(r, "transcriptId")

transcriptId, err := strconv.ParseInt(id, 10, 64)

if err := r.ParseMultipartForm(32 << 20); err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
    http.Error(w, http.StatusText(http.StatusBadRequest), http.StatusBadRequest)
    return
}

file, handler, err := r.FormFile("file")
```

Flutter upload code

```
class FileUploadView extends StatefulWidget {
  const FileUploadView({super.key});

  @override
  State<FileUploadView> createState() => _FileUploadViewState();
}

class _FileUploadViewState extends State<FileUploadView> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(
      (_) => showSnackBar(context),
    );
    super.initState();
  }

  FilePickerResult? result;
  PlatformFile? file;
  Response? response;
  String? progress;
  Dio dio = Dio();
  String success = 'Your file was uploaded successfully';
  String failure = 'Your file could not be uploaded';
  bool replaceFile = false;

  selectFile() async {
    FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform
        .pickFiles(type: FileType.any, withReadStream: true);

    if (result != null) {
      file = result.files.single;
    }

    setState(() {});
  }

  Future<void> uploadFile(BuildContext context, User user) async {
    final navigator = Navigator.of(context);

    const storage = FlutterSecureStorage();

    String? token = await storage.read(key: 'jwt');

    dio.options.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/octet-stream';
    dio.options.headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer $token";
    dio.options.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*';
    dio.options.baseUrl = user.fileUrl;

    final uploader = ChunkedUploader(dio);

    try {
      response = await uploader.upload(
        fileKey: 'file',
        method: 'POST',
        fileName: file!.name,
        fileSize: file!.size,
        fileDataStream: file!.readStream!,
        maxChunkSize: 32000000,
        path: user.fileUrl,
        onUploadProgress: (progress) => setState(
          () {
            progress;
          },
        ),
      );

      if (response!.statusCode == 200) {
        user.snackBarType = SnackBarType.success;

        user.snackBarMessage = success;

        navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
            RoutePaths.matterTabs, (route) => false);
      } else {
        user.snackBarType = SnackBarType.failure;

        user.snackBarMessage = failure;

        navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
            RoutePaths.matterTabs, (route) => false);
      }
    } on DioException catch (e) {
      if (e.response?.statusCode == 404) {
        print('status code 404');
      } else {
        print(e.message ?? 'no error message available');
        print(e.requestOptions.toString());
        print(e.response.toString());
        print(e.type.toString());
        print(user.fileUrl);
        print(dio.options.baseUrl);
        print(dio.options.headers);
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    User user = Provider.of<User>(context, listen: false);
    
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text(
          'app name',
          maxLines: 1,
          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
        ),
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
          onPressed: () => {
            Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                RoutePaths.matterTabs, (route) => false)
          },
        ),
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                const SizedBox(height: 12),
                const Text(
                  'Select and Upload File',
                  maxLines: 4,
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  softWrap: true,
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 24),

                Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  //show file name here
                  child: progress == null
                      ? const Text("Progress: 0%")
                      : Text(
                          "Progress: $progress",
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        ),
                  //show progress status here
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 24),
                Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  //show file name here
                  child: file == null
                      ? const Text(
                          'Choose File',
                        )
                      : Text(
                          file!.name,
                        ),
                  //basename is from path package, to get filename from path
                  //check if file is selected, if yes then show file name
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 24),
                ElevatedButton.icon(
                  onPressed: () async {
                    selectFile();
                  },
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.folder_open),
                  label: const Text(
                    "CHOOSE FILE",
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 24),

                //if selectedfile is null then show empty container
                //if file is selected then show upload button
                file == null
                    ? Container()
                    : ElevatedButton.icon(
                        onPressed: () async {
                          if (user.fileExists) {
                            _replaceExistingFile(context, user);
                          } else {
                            uploadFile(context, user);
                          }
                        },
                        icon: const Icon(Icons.upload),
                        label: const Text(
                          "UPLOAD FILE",
                        ),
                      ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  _replaceExistingFile(BuildContext context, User user) {
    bool firstPress = true;

    return showDialog<bool>(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: const Text('File Exists'),
          content: Text("Do you want to replace ${user.uploadFileName}?"),
          actions: <Widget>[
            TextButton(
              child: const Text('Cancel'),
              onPressed: () {
                {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop(false);
                }
              },
            ),
            TextButton(
              child: const Text('Replace'),
              onPressed: () async {
                if (firstPress) {
                  firstPress = false;
                  {
                    uploadFile(context, user);
                  }
                } else {}
              },
            )
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are talking about [dio 5.3.2](https://pub.dev/packages/dio), repository [`cfug/dio`](https://github.com/cfug/dio)

```
dio.options.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/octet-stream';
```

You are setting the `Content-Type` to `'application/octet-stream'` in Dio's options. That might not be correct if you are uploading a multipart form data. In the context of file uploads, the `Content-Type` typically has to be `multipart/form-data`.

Try to remove the manual setting of the `Content-Type`, or change it to `'multipart/form-data'`.
Especially [since 5.3.1](https://github.com/cfug/dio/blob/3ad39477f1b36d6d2b51ed7588b6bf17c898d28c/dio/CHANGELOG.md#531): "Deprecate `MultipartFile` constructor in favor `MultipartFile.fromStream`"

Also, if your request contains custom headers, they should be added to the `AllowedHeaders` in your server's CORS configuration.

Remember that some headers may cause a request to be preflighted, meaning that an OPTIONS request will be made before the actual request, to check that the server will accept the request according to its CORS headers.

Since you are modifying the headers, ensure that the server is set up to handle preflight requests correctly, and that the headers you are setting in your client code are all included in the server's `AllowedHeaders` list.

See also [Flutter Web: Some Notes / How to enable CORS on the server?](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-web-for-an-enterprise-app-a056fb4e26d1#6649) from [Vinay Shankri](https://github.com/shankri).

---

You could also get back to a simple HTTP Request with Dio (see "[Mastering HTTP Requests in Flutter with Dio Package](https://medium.com/@azizndao/mastering-http-requests-in-flutter-with-dio-package-975b75002911)" from [Abdou Aziz NDAO](https://twitter.com/_abdouaziz_)), and check it is working.
Then, add back your code little by little, to see at what point that would fail.

Comment: I did try http but the same result. Previously it was making an options request but now it isn't. The headers for the server are in the question.

Comment: @markhorrocks Speaking of headers, did you test the `Content-Type` change I suggest in the answer?

Comment: @markhorrocks "Previously it was making an options request but now it isn't": if you see in the logs "returning a status code 200 for the OPTIONS request", is it safe to assume that now, it is still making an options request?

Comment: Not yet. I just saw this answer., Be assured I will. My code looks like I do use multipart from stream but I'm not sure.

Comment: It's no longer making an options request

Comment: @markhorrocks OK. Can you edit/clarify the question then? What was working, what has changed, what is no longer working?

Comment: I had been shuffling between dio and http implementations. In the code above I do get a 200 for an options request in api logs but then an immediate disconnect from my client. I did remove the content type header.

Comment: @markhorrocks I have seen your solution: well done.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that this is a Dio issue. I was able to get this to work using http. I wanted to use Dio because of the callbacks giving me a progress meter.

The code below works. It's not a minimal working version, it's my full file upload page code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:logger/logger.dart';
import 'package:file_picker/file_picker.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:myapp/ui/helpers/show_snack_bar.dart';
import 'package:myapp/core/models/user.dart';
import 'package:myapp/core/models/company.dart';
import 'package:myapp/core/constants/app_constants.dart';
import 'package:flutter_secure_storage/flutter_secure_storage.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:async';

class FileUploadView extends StatefulWidget {
  const FileUploadView({super.key});

  @override
  State<FileUploadView> createState() => FileUploadViewState();
}

class FileUploadViewState extends State<FileUploadView> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(
      (_) => showSnackBar(context),
    );
    super.initState();
  }

  FilePickerResult? result;
  PlatformFile? file;

  String? progress;
  String success = 'Your file was uploaded successfully';
  String failure = 'Your file could not be uploaded';
  bool replaceFile = false;
  bool isLoading = false;
  bool firstPress = true;

  var logger = Logger(
    printer: PrettyPrinter(),
  );

  selectFile() async {
    result = (await FilePicker.platform
        .pickFiles(type: FileType.any, withData: true));

    if (result != null) {
      file = result?.files.single;
    }

    setState(() {});
  }

  Future<dynamic> uploadFile(BuildContext context, User user) async {
    final navigator = Navigator.of(context);

    const storage = FlutterSecureStorage();

    String? token = await storage.read(key: 'jwt');

    Map<String, String> headers = {
      "Authorization": "Bearer $token",
    };

    final bytes = file?.bytes;

    if (file == null || bytes == null) return;

    final multipartFile =
        http.MultipartFile.fromBytes('file', bytes, filename: file?.name);

    final request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', Uri.parse(user.fileUrl));

    request.files.add(multipartFile);

    request.headers.addAll(headers);

    user.snackBarMessage = 'Uploading file, please wait';

    progress = 'Uploading file, please wait';

    isLoading = true;

    setState(() {});

    try {
      final responseStream = await request.send();

      final response = await http.Response.fromStream(responseStream);

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        user.snackBarType = SnackBarType.success;

        user.snackBarMessage = success;

        navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
            RoutePaths.matterTabs, (route) => false);
      } else {
        user.snackBarType = SnackBarType.failure;

        user.snackBarMessage = failure;

        navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
            RoutePaths.matterTabs, (route) => false);
      }
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      logger.d(e);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    User user = Provider.of<User>(context, listen: false);

    Company company = Provider.of<Company>(context, listen: false);

    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text(
          company.companyName,
          maxLines: 1,
          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
        ),
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
          onPressed: () => {
            Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                RoutePaths.matterTabs, (route) => false)
          },
        ),
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                const SizedBox(height: 12),
                const Text(
                  'Select and Upload File',
                  maxLines: 4,
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  softWrap: true,
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 24),
                Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  child: progress == null
                      ? const Text("Progress: 0%")
                      : Text(
                          "Progress: $progress",
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 24),
                Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  child: file == null
                      ? const Text(
                          'Choose File',
                        )
                      : Text(
                          file!.name,
                        ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 24),
                FilledButton.icon(
                  onPressed: () async {
                    selectFile();
                  },
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.folder_open),
                  label: const Text(
                    "CHOOSE FILE",
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 24),
                file == null
                    ? Container()
                    : FilledButton.icon(
                        onPressed: () async {
                          if (firstPress) {
                            firstPress = false;
                            if (user.fileExists) {
                              _replaceExistingFile(context, user);
                            } else {
                              uploadFile(context, user);
                            }
                          }
                        },
                        icon: const Icon(Icons.upload),
                        label: const Text(
                          "UPLOAD FILE",
                        ),
                      ),
                isLoading
                    ? const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
                    : Container(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  _replaceExistingFile(BuildContext context, User user) {
    bool firstPress = true;

    return showDialog<bool>(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: const Text('File Exists'),
          content: Text("Do you want to replace ${user.uploadFileName}?"),
          actions: <Widget>[
            FilledButton(
              child: const Text('Cancel'),
              onPressed: () {
                {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop(false);
                }
              },
            ),
            FilledButton(
              child: const Text('Replace'),
              onPressed: () async {
                if (firstPress) {
                  firstPress = false;
                  {
                    uploadFile(context, user);
                  }
                } else {}
              },
            )
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Good workaround (that I mentioned in my answer) to use http instead of dio package to make your query. Upvoted.